# mail to in an existing php code

Tags: php, mailto

i have this code:

```
if($this->helix3->getParam('contact_email')) $output .= '<li class="sp-contact-email"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> ' . $this->helix3->getParam('contact_email') . '</li>';

        $output .= '<ul>';

        return $output;
```

I would like that click in the frontpage will send an email to the result of the getParam('contact_email')

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you need to use an anchor tag with `mailto:` in the href:

```
if($this->helix3->getParam('contact_email')){
  $email=$this->helix3->getParam('contact_email');
  $output .= '<li class="sp-contact-email"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> <a href="mailto:'.$email.'">' . $email . '</a></li>';
}

        $output .= '<ul>';

        return $output;
```

Comment: yes...in the frontend of the website i can just see the mail xxx@123.com, but can't click on it to send an email

Comment: This should work, I've already tested it.... `<a href="mailto:user@domain.com">send mail</a>` that is basically the result of the above

Comment: thx trey...i feel so stupid and tired. you gave me light <code>if($this->helix3->getParam('enable_contactinfo')) {

   $output = '<ul class="sp-contact-info">';

   
   if($this->helix3->getParam('contact_email')) $output .= '<a href="mailto:xxx@xxx.it"><li class="sp-contact-email"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>xxx@xxx.it</a> ' . 

          $output .= '<ul>';

   return $output;</code>